# When Tensoarboard adds to code my logs doesn't print

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard

I have runned my code before without tesorboard, and also I have tried working with tensorboard with another code too,
but when I just add this two lines to my code, my logs doesn't print.

```py
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter("./runs/tiny")
```

Comment: You should share your code. Without code, we can not even guess.

Comment: Sorry, I add the two lines that after adding them my code didn't run

Comment: Which version of `torch` are you using?

Comment: I use pytorch version 1.4

Comment: I realized it runs but the logs that had printed before doesn't print now!